# How to ask the user for access permission to another application using Swift in macOS

Tags: swift, macos

I am building an app that needs to read or write from another one which is Spotify, but currently i can't get the alert for asking the user for permission to show up.

Here is what I did for now :

- I added [image] to my .plist file
- have a simple window, with a button in it, when the button is clicked I ask the user for access to spotify permission :

```swift
 @IBAction func okey(_ sender: NSButton) {
          let target = NSAppleEventDescriptor(bundleIdentifier: "com.spotify.client")
        let permission = AEDeterminePermissionToAutomateTarget(target.aeDesc, typeWildCard, typeWildCard,false)
        print(permission)

        }
```

When I try to execute the function here is the error i get with the status -600, which means the program doesn't find the app (Spotify is already open):
[image]

I am on macOS 13.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. It is simple.

1. You need to remove the Sandbox specifications from your app configuration:
   [image]
2. on Hardened Runtime, check Apple Events checkbox:
   [image]